# type of expression is ambiguous without more context for NSNotification

Tags: swift, nsnotification

I have migrated my code from XCode 8.0 to XCode 9.4

Now I am getting this error:

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
private let visageNoFaceDetectedNotification = NSNotification(name: "visageNoFaceDetectedNotification", object: nil)
```

Everything was working fine in XCode 8.0.

I think because of swift version changed, it is happening.

Comment: In particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928864/1187415 for the recommended way of defining custom notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 4 changed how you create notification names.

Change your code to:

```
private let visageNoFaceDetectedNotification = NSNotification(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "visageNoFaceDetectedNotification"), object: nil)
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `NSNotification.Name("visageNoFaceDetectedNotification")` without the "rawValue:". (And unless I am mistaken, this changed with Swift 3 already.)